# Second queue is not defined [python]

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a 3 processes running in one script. Process 1 passes data to Process 2, and then Process 2 passes data to Process 3. When I put data to queue2, error occurs that "Global name "queue2" is not defined", I am stuck on this error now...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

queue1 = mp.Queue()
queue2 = mp.Queue()

p1 = mp.Process(target=f2, args=(queue1,))
p1.start()

p2 = mp.Process(target=f3, args=(queue2,))
p2.start()

f1()

def f1():
    # do something to a get x
    queue1.put(x)
def f2(q):
    a = q.get()
    # do something to a, to produce b
    queue2.put(b) # error happens here: Global name "queue2" is not defined
def f3(q):
    c = q.get()
    # keeping processing c...
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using global names across processes. That would require sharing the variable across said processes. When you build the process you pass the queue as an argument.  Please just do `q.put(b)` . You should do the same in f1 as well. Once you start  using `mp` you have to stop thinking that `p1.start()` will happen before `p2.start()` unless you control the processes / threads via locks.

Answer (score 1):

Just as you passed `queue1` to `f2`, you also need to pass `queue2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the queues as global:

```
def f2(q):
    global queue2
    a = q.get()
    queue2.put(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works :

```
import multiprocessing as mp

queue1 = mp.Queue()
queue2 = mp.Queue()


def f1(q):
    x = 5
    # do something to a get x
    q.put(x)

def f2(in_queue, out_queue):
    a = in_queue.get()
    b = a + 2
    # do something to a, to produce b
    out_queue.put(b) 

def f3(q):
    c = q.get()
    print c

f1(queue1)

p1 = mp.Process(target=f2, args=(queue1, queue2))
p1.start()

p2 = mp.Process(target=f3, args=(queue2,))
p2.start()
```

Your code doesn't return the error you seem to have, it returns "f2 not defined" since you when you spawn the process `p1`, `f2` is not a defined variable yet. The rule when you fork is that at creation time your processes must see the variables they use, i.e. they must be in the current scope.

To put it clearly, at spawning process time you inherit the current namespace from  the parent process.